# Trying to Retrieve and OU from Active Directory, then set new properties on an OU using a Directory Entry in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

This method is trying to get all OU's directory below the Center ou, one at a time, that match the names in my list of Center objects.

Next for each one it tries to set a couple properties (that have not been created before)

It gets the OU, goes to the .Add branch and crashes. What am I misunderstanding.

I get exception with "Unspecified error\n\n", with the following call stack

at System.DirectoryServices.Interop.UnsafeNativeMethods.IAds.PutEx(Int32 lnControlCode, String bstrName, Object vProp)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.OnInsertComplete(Int32 index, Object value)
   at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
   at System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.Add(Object value)
   at StudentPortalDevFixTool.Form1.buttonfixCenters_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\TFS\StudentPortalDevFixTool\StudentPortalDevFixTool\Form1.cs:line 599

I've done this before but it was like 8 years ago. Thanks.

```
private void buttonfixCenters_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            string adConnStr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DeUrl"];
            string adServerUser = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DeAcct"];
            string adServerPassword = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DePwd"];
            string adServerContainer = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AD_DomainOu"];
            // looks like this: "DC=AD,DC=MyDomain,DC=org"

            if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( adConnStr ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerUser) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerPassword) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerContainer) )
            {
                string adName = textBox_adname_unlock.Text;

                try
                {
                    DirectoryEntry startSearch = new DirectoryEntry( adConnStr, adServerUser, adServerPassword );
                    foreach ( Center ctr in CenterListFromCdss )
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            DirectorySearcher Mysearcher;

                            if ( startSearch == null )
                            {
                                throw new Exception( "No root in BuildDirectoryEntry(...)" );
                            }

                            Mysearcher = new DirectorySearcher( startSearch );

                            Mysearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                            Mysearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(ou=" + ctr.shname + "))";

                            SearchResult result = Mysearcher.FindOne();

                            DirectoryEntry centerDe;

                            if ( result == null)
                            {
                                centerDe = null;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                centerDe  = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                            }


                            if ( centerDe != null )
                            {
                                centerDe.Properties[ "UserPropertyCache" ].Value = true; 
                                centerDe.RefreshCache();

                                if ( result.Properties.Contains( "telexNumber" ) )
                                {
                                    centerDe.Properties[ "telexNumber" ].Value = ctr.ctrid;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    centerDe.Properties[ "telexNumber" ].Add( ctr.ctrid );// GOES BOOM HERE!
                                }

                                if ( result.Properties.Contains( "centerCode" ) )
                                {
                                    centerDe.Properties[ "centerCode" ].Value = ctr.ctrCode;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    centerDe.Properties[ "centerCode" ].Add( ctr.ctrCode );
                                }

                                //centerDe.Properties[ "telexNumber" ].Value = ctr.ctrid;
                                //centerDe.Properties[ "centerCode" ].Value = ctr.ctrCode;

                                centerDe.CommitChanges();
                                centerDe.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch ( Exception ex )
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show( "Exception: " + ex.ToString() );
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Answer was mostly there, figured it out in the comments, i was passing Int64, instead of string or int. adding .ToString() fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible cause I can guess at is that `ctr.ctrid` is `null` or some weird type it can't handle. But the error message of the exception will confirm that, if you can share that.

But some other comments:

```
Mysearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
```

`Subtree` is the default, so you don't need to set it if that's what you want.

```
centerDe.Properties[ "UserPropertyCache" ].Value = true;
```

`UserPropertyCache` is not an AD attribute. I think you are trying to use the [`UsePropertyCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.usepropertycache) (notice, no "r") property of `DirectoryEntry`, in which case you would do this:

```
centerDe.UsePropertyCache = true;
```

But `true` is the default anyway, so you don't need to do that.

Then this:

```
centerDe.RefreshCache();
```

Calling `RefreshCache()` tells it to go out to AD and retrieve *every* attribute for the object. The same thing happens when you read an attribute using `Properties` for the first time and the attribute is not in the cache yet. You could tell it to only retrieve the attributes you actually want to look at by doing this:

```
centerDe.RefreshCache(new [] { "telexNumber", "centerCode" });
```

That will tell it to only retrieve those two attributes.

However, you don't even need to do that. All you're doing is adding a new value, so you don't really care what is already there.

I see that you're switching between `.Value =` and `.Add()` depending on if there's a value already there, but you don't need to. You can just use `.Add()` and it will add a value whether there is something already there or not.

And then there is this:

```
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    throw;
}
```

Is there a reason for this? As it is, there is no point to having the try/catch block at all if you are only going to rethrow it.

You can also simplify your code a little by using the [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/continue) statement.

Here is your code with all my recommendations included:

```cs
private void buttonfixCenters_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string adConnStr = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DeUrl"];
    string adServerUser = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DeAcct"];
    string adServerPassword = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DePwd"];
    string adServerContainer = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AD_DomainOu"];
    // looks like this: "DC=AD,DC=MyDomain,DC=org"

    if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( adConnStr ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerUser) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerPassword) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(adServerContainer) )
    {
        string adName = textBox_adname_unlock.Text;

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry startSearch = new DirectoryEntry( adConnStr, adServerUser, adServerPassword );
            foreach ( Center ctr in CenterListFromCdss )
            {
                DirectorySearcher Mysearcher;

                if ( startSearch == null )
                {
                    throw new Exception( "No root in BuildDirectoryEntry(...)" );
                }

                Mysearcher = new DirectorySearcher( startSearch );

                Mysearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=organizationalUnit)(ou=" + ctr.shname + "))";

                SearchResult result = Mysearcher.FindOne();

                if ( result == null) continue;

                DirectoryEntry centerDe  = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

                centerDe.Properties[ "telexNumber" ].Add( ctr.ctrid.ToString() );
                centerDe.Properties[ "centerCode" ].Add( ctr.ctrCode.ToString() );

                centerDe.CommitChanges();
                centerDe.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "Exception: " + ex.ToString() );
        }
    }
}
```

This will probably still throw an exception at `.Add( ctr.ctrid )`, but you will have to share what the error message is before I can help with that.

Comment: The CtrId = 2

The RefreshCache stuff, thanks, i got that from a comment on a different thread, now i understand what's going on.

The catch and just rethrow an exception, is so i can put a breakpoint in the method that throws the exception. It's purely for debugging. In a less modest app *(this is a 1 time throw away tool) I'd also log it there.

I updated it to show the exception messasge, probabaly while you were typing this answer.

I get exception with "Unspecified error\n\n",

Call stack is in the original message as the message isn't too helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: So the value is `2`. In the little testing I did, I am guessing that it's not an `int`. Since if I do `.Add(2)` it works fine. But if I do `.Add(2d)` (forcing it to `decimal` type), then it fails with the same error. Just call `.ToString()` on it. I updated my answer.

Comment: I added .ToString() (As it was Int64) and it sets now, but when i CommitChanges, I get "The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist."

How do i add a new not existingSetting like CenterCode?

Comment: That would require modifying your AD schema. There are a few tutorials online if you search for ["add attribute to active directory"](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+attribute+to+active+directory). You would have to be a domain admin to do this.

Comment: Thanks man, if I Comment out CenterCode it works, and now that you remember that i remember having CenterCode added of the old ad server way back when.